# Working with SplClassLoader.php and namespaces

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

```
<?php
    //The basic Code.
    require_once("SplClassLoader.php");
     $loader = new SplClassLoader('test', 'lib');
        $loader->register();

    use test\database\Connector;
    ?>

    <?php
    namespace test\database;
    class Database {

    }
    ?>


    <?php
    namespace test\database\Connector;
    class Connector extends text\database\Database {

    }
    ?>
```

my file structure looks like this

\

-index.php

-splclassloader.php

\test

\test\database

\test\database\Database.php

\test\database\Connector.php

Its not loading the connector class.
What is it that I don't understand here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to autoload classes that are mapping folders to namespaces (I'm assuming that is the case) make sure that your namespaces only include the folder names and omit class names.  The `use` statement, on the other hand, would not omit the class name.

Using the namespace of `test\database\Connector` and then defining a class `Connector` means that you would instantiate the object using:

```
$connecter = new \test\database\Connector\Connector();
```

I'm guessing you have an additional subnamespace `Connector` that isn't needed.  Namespace `test\database\Connector` should be `test\database`.